# Where are open-end funds traded?

Tags: mutual-funds, financial-literacy

From Wikipedia, I learned that close-end funds and ETFs are traded over exchanges, and open-end funds are not.
I wonder where open-end funds are traded? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I assume that *mutual* funds are being
discussed here.

As Bryce says, open-ended funds are bought from the mutual fund company and redeemed from the fund company.  Except in very rare circumstances, 
they exist only 
as bits in the fund company's computers and not as share certificates (whether paper or electronic) that can be delivered from the selling broker to the buying broker on a stock exchange. Effectively, the fund company is the sole market
maker: if you want to buy, ask the fund company at
what price it will sell them to you
(and it will tell you the answer only after 4 pm that day when a sale at
that price is no longer possible unless you committed to buy, say, 100
shares and authorized the fund company to withdraw the correct amount
from your bank account or other liquid asset after the price was known). 
Ditto if you want
to sell: the mutual fund company will tell you what price it will give you
only after 4 pm that day and you cannot sell at that price unless you
had committed to accept whatever the company was going to give you for
your shares (or had said "Send me $1000 and sell as many shares of mine
as are needed to give me proceeds of $1000 cash.")

Comment: The fund company is effectively the sole market maker, but note that there is no bid-ask price spread; both buys and sells are executed at a single price, the net asset value.

Comment: Yes, that's why I pointed out the difference that you don't get to know the exact price until the market closes and the net asset value is determined by the closing price. And for load funds, there _is_ a difference between what you get to buy at and what you get to sell at.

Comment: @mgkrebbs  are you sure thus us always the case ? in the UK I had some unit trusts that had different sell and buy prices

Comment: @Pepone - You're right that some funds and unit trusts are _load_ funds, that is, they charge more to buy then they will give you when you sell (for the same net asset value).  I've dealt exclusively with _no-load_ funds for so long (which use the same price for both), that I didn't think to mention such unwanted sales charges exist on some funds.

Answer (score 3):

Close-end funds just means there's a fixed number of shares available, so if you want to buy some you must purchase from other existing owners, typically through an exchange.

Open-end funds mean the company providing the shares is still selling them, so you can buy them directly from the company.  Some can also be traded on exchanges as well.